# Updating dates from 19XX to 20XX in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where dates have been incorrectly entered as 19XX rather than 20XX.

Is it possible to have an update query that will amend any value in a particular field from 19XX to 20XX (UK date format) where the original date is less than 01/01/2000?

For example

```
ID    FieldA
123   23/11/1917
```

would become

```
ID    FieldA
123   23/11/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you may have correct date in the latter half of the 20th century and it is only the earlier half of the century you need to update (please confirm this) then:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    date_column = ADD_MONTHS( date_column, 12 * 100 )
WHERE  date_column >= DATE '1900-01-01'
AND    date_column <  DATE '1950-01-01';
```

If you do want to change the dates for all years in the 20th century then:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    date_column = ADD_MONTHS( date_column, 12 * 100 )
WHERE  date_column >= DATE '1900-01-01'
AND    date_column < DATE '2000-01-01';
```

Note: you need to use the `ADD_MONTHS` function rather than adding `INTERVAL '100' YEAR(3)` since there are dates in the 20th century that are not in the 21st century (i.e. 1900-02-29).

Answer (score 0):

If `FieldA` is a `date`, then you can do:

```
select (case when fieldA < date '2000-01-01'
             then fieldA + interval '100' year(3)
             else fieldA
        end)
```

Comment: I'm getting ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small

Comment: This needs to be `INTERVAL '100' YEAR(3)` with the precision of the year specified to at least 3 digits. However, it won't work for all dates as `1900-02-29` will throw an error as year 2000 was not a leap year so you should not use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of shortened `YY` date format. To quote the docs:

> If you use the TO_DATE function with the YY datetime format element,
>   then the year returned always has the same first 2 digits as the
>   current year.

Therefore, `to_date(to_char(fieldA, 'ddmmyy'), 'ddmmyy')` should do what you need. Be careful though, if there are dates with years less than 1900 or over 2100, they'll be converted as well.